# Get hourly averages only of mondays of entire year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, hour

I have a dataset that looks as follows: 
[The dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgHN2.png)

I have a big list of orders with there traveled distance for the entire year of 2018. To predict the orders for the future I want to calculate the total orders per Hour for all the Mondays of the year. So, the average number of orders between 00:00:00 -:01:00:00 the average orders between 01:00:00 - 02:00:00 until 23:00:00 - 24:00:00 only on Mondays. They should not include the orders on other weekdays.

What I have so far is:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('Finalorders.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])

week_dfsum = df_data.groupby(df_data['datetime'].dt.weekday_name).sum()
week_dfsum = df_data.groupby(df_data['datetime'].dt.weekday_name).sum()
pprint(week_dfsum)
pprint(week_dfmean)
```

But I don't know how to only include the orders on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. After you produce a column called "Day of the week", filter it by Monday's using:

```
df[df['Day_of_Week'] == 1]
```

This will return only values from Mondays.